# How to Bind apache with two ports?

Tags: apache, load-balancing

I am having to servers giving services in two different ports 8080, 2379
how to configure apache to listen to the above ports and forwards the request to available server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To tell Apache it should listen on specific port(s) add the `Listen` directive in the configuration (e.g. `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`). It can be specified multiple times, as in:

```
Listen 8080
Listen 2379
```

Details on this directive can be found [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#listen).

This will serve the content from `DocumentRoot` on these ports. If you want a different configuration on each port, you need to take a look at [`VirtualHost`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html) directive, which essentially allows you to host multiple websites on the same socket (IP/port).